# if a key exist, sort it to be the last element of array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [os]  => win7
    [lang]  => eng
    [page]  => 5
    [type]  => 6
    [sex]  => 1
    [name] => mary
)
```

If array exit a key[page]. let it be the last element

how can I do?

I find end(); But not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($ar['key']))
{
    $temp = $ar['key'];
    unset($ar['key']);
    $ar['key'] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way,

```
$a=Array
(
    [os]  => win7
    [lang]  => eng
    [page]  => 5
    [type]  => 6
    [sex]  => 1
    [name] => mary
);

if(isset($a['page'])){
 $val=$a['page'];   
 unset ($a['page']);
 array_push($a, $val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function to check particular key exists or not and if exists then move it to last

```
<?php
$my_array = Array
(
    'os'  => 'win7',
    'lang'  => 'eng',
    'page'  => '5',
    'type'  => '6',
    'sex'  => '1',
    'name' => 'mary',
);

$key_check = 'page';

if(array_key_exists($key_check, $my_array))
{
    $tmp = $my_array[$key_check];
    unset($my_array[$key_check]);
    $my_array[$key_check] = $tmp;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_array);
?>
```